# Create T-SQL query from Excel Formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, formula

I need to create a SQL script that will prorata summed values across an invoice period on a monthly basis and create the necessary additional columns to display the results. I have this as an Excel formula.

[image: excel formula]

Comment: Hello, please check : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi there welcome to SO, what have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I've tried writing the bits that count the number of days in the invoice period, that average the invoice on a daily basis so i have the source data, it's a matter of recreating the prorationing function and saving the results on a monthly basis. I could probably do this a very long way and replicate the equation on a month by month basis, but I can't think of a more simple solution.

Comment: please post the structure of the tables you are using, and show us the script you used, this will be helpfull to make an answer to your question